# Rounded tables in Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table, rounded-corners

Bootstrap 3 has dropped rounded corners on tables. Which styles should I apply to get them back when I apply the `.table-bordered` class, please?

**UPDATE**

So far I've come to this code, with no effect.

CSS taken from Bootstrap 2.3.2:

```
.table-bordered
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.table-bordered thead:first-child tr:first-child > th:first-child, .table-bordered tbody:first-child tr:first-child > td:first-child, .table-bordered tbody:first-child tr:first-child > th:first-child
{
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
}

.table-bordered thead:last-child tr:last-child > th:first-child, .table-bordered tbody:last-child tr:last-child > td:first-child, .table-bordered tbody:last-child tr:last-child > th:first-child, .table-bordered tfoot:last-child tr:last-child > td:first-child, .table-bordered tfoot:last-child tr:last-child > th:first-child
{
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 50%">
                Config. Name
            </th>
            <th>
                API Calls
            </th>
            <th>
                Current Amount
            </th>
            <th>
                Actions
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/searchsources/details">Agennda</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                2,876
            </td>
            <td>
                $ 80.67
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/searchsources/details">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 156, accepted):

If you surround the table with a panel you get your rounded corners.

Like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        ....
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I had to remove cell's top border of the first row, but works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, that actually works and seems to be responsive in diff resolutions

Comment: nice... this should be the real answer.

Comment: i love these kind of accidents!

Comment: The only issue I've found with this solution is that the table border shrinks to less than the width of the table if the window is too small, resulting in parts of the table not being enclosed in a border.

Comment: .panel dont haVe border-radius with my Bootstrap

Comment: Panels are now cards in bootstrap 4. So simply replace `<div class="panel panel-default">` with `<div class="card">`. Also, creating another nested div sorrounding the table as the card body will make it look cleaner `<div class="card-body">`

Comment: As for Angular 4, this solution doesn't work anymore. As @MarceloVilla says, use card instead.

Answer (score 28):

"table-responsive" goes on a div that wraps the table, not on the table itself.

In normalize.less there is the table reset which include border-collapse:collapse. This was not in the 2.x of Bootstrap. Because of this new reset, there are no rounded corners as those have to be border-collapse:separate. You have to make a separate class and set it up accordingly.

```
       <table class="table table-curved">
```

Only works with "table-hover" and "table-striped" NOT table-bordered. The borders are included in this style.

```
.table-curved {
    border-collapse: separate;
}
.table-curved {
    border: solid #ccc 1px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-left:0px;
}
.table-curved td, .table-curved th {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.table-curved th {
    border-top: none;
}
.table-curved th:first-child {
    border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
}
.table-curved th:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
}
.table-curved th:only-child{
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}
.table-curved tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 6px;
}
.table-curved tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 6px 0;
}
```

LESS

```
  //  Added Rounded Corner Tables 
.table-curved {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border: solid @table-border-color 1px;
  border-radius: @table-radius;
  border-left:0px;

    td, th {
      border-left: 1px solid @table-border-color;
      border-top: 1px solid @table-border-color;
    }

    th {
      border-top: none;
    }

    th:first-child {
      border-radius: @table-radius 0 0 0;
    }

    th:last-child {
      border-radius: 0 @table-radius 0 0;
    }

    th:only-child{
      border-radius: @table-radius @table-radius 0 0;
    }

    tr:last-child td:first-child {
      border-radius: 0 0 0 @table-radius;
    }

    tr:last-child td:last-child {
      border-radius: 0 0 @table-radius 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Helpful! I need to set it up without inner borders and that seems tricky. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: This is the perfect answer! the marked answer is not working if you zoom-in

Answer (score 10):

Using Christina's answer and this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525503/select-only-the-first-row-in-a-table-with-css) , i came up with this CSS to get the rounded corners in tables with or without THEAD.

```
.table-curved {
   border-collapse: separate;
   border: solid #ccc 1px;
   border-radius: 6px;
   border-left: 0px;
   border-top: 0px;
}
.table-curved > thead:first-child > tr:first-child > th {
    border-bottom: 0px;
    border-top: solid #ccc 1px;
}
.table-curved td, .table-curved th {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.table-curved > :first-child > :first-child > :first-child {
    border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
}
.table-curved > :first-child > :first-child > :last-child {
    border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
}
.table-curved > :last-child > :last-child > :first-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 6px;
}
.table-curved > :last-child > :last-child > :last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 6px 0;
}
```

Comment: Worked fine, except for tables with only one column in thead or tfoot. If you intent to use colspan="100%", you'll need to include those CSS rules:

.table-curved > :first-child > :first-child > :first-child:last-child {
 border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.table-curved > :last-child > :last-child > :first-child:last-child {
 border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
}

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are not using the source less-files. However, in normalize.less, bootstrap 3.0RC is adding:

```
// ==========================================================================
// Tables
// ==========================================================================

//
// Remove most spacing between table cells.
//

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

This border-collapse thing destroys the rounded borders on tables.
So, by simply override that in your table-bordered you turn on the effect:

```
.table-bordered
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;

    border-collapse: inherit;
}
```

I think it may work.

Answer (score 2):

The following one works quite nicely for me:

```
.table-curved {
    border-collapse: separate;
}
.table-curved {
    border: solid #ccc 1px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.table-curved td, .table-curved th {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.table-curved tr > *:first-child {
    border-left: 0px;
}
.table-curved tr:first-child > * {
    border-top: 0px;
}
```

Though it does not of course work for nested tables.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of bootstrappiness:

```
.table-curved {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border: solid @table-border-color 1px;
    border-radius: @border-radius-base;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-top: 0px;
    > thead:first-child > tr:first-child > th {
        border-bottom: 0px;
        border-top: solid @table-border-color 1px;
    }
    td, th {
        border-left: 1px solid @table-border-color;
        border-top: 1px solid @table-border-color;
    }
    > :first-child > :first-child > :first-child {
        border-radius: @border-radius-base 0 0 0;
    }
    > :first-child > :first-child > :last-child {
        border-radius: 0 @border-radius-base 0 0;
    }
    > :last-child > :last-child > :first-child {
        border-radius: 0 0 0 @border-radius-base;
    }
    > :last-child > :last-child > :last-child {
        border-radius: 0 0 @border-radius-base 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution that may be far simpler than the above ones. This will select the first and last `th` elements and apply a border to their respective corners. You can then add a radius to the overall table.

```
.table {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
th:first-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}
th:last-of-type {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 1 cell in the first row or last row this one will work.

(Added a fix to the code of: Ruben Stolk)

```
.table-curved {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border: solid @table-border-color 1px;
  border-radius: @border-radius-base;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-top: 0px;
  > thead:first-child > tr:first-child > th {
    border-bottom: 0px;
    border-top: solid @table-border-color 1px;
  }
  td, th {
    border-left: 1px solid @table-border-color;
    border-top: 1px solid @table-border-color;
  }
  > :first-child > :first-child > :first-child {
    border-radius: @border-radius-base 0 0 0;
  }
  > :first-child > :first-child > :last-child {
    border-radius: 0 @border-radius-base 0 0;
  }
  > :first-child > :first-child > :only-child{
    border-radius: @border-radius-base @border-radius-base 0 0;
  }
  > :last-child > :last-child > :first-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 @border-radius-base;
  }
  > :last-child > :last-child > :last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 @border-radius-base 0;
  }
  > :last-child > :last-child > :only-child{
    border-radius: 0 0 @border-radius-base @border-radius-base;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above on wrapping the table with a panel (`<div class="panel panel-default">`) seems to work the best.

However, as mentioned in the comments, you do need to remove the top border on the table.

I used this SCSS to do this, so thought I would share:

```
// remove extra top border on tables wrapped in a panel
.panel {
  & > .table-responsive > .table.table-bordered, & > .table.table-bordered {
    & > tbody:first-child, & > thead:first-child {
      & > tr:first-child {
        td, th {
          border-top: none;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **table-bordered-curved** instead **table-bordered**

```
.table-bordered-curved {
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}

.table-bordered-curved thead tr:last-child th,
.table-bordered-curved thead tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}

.table-bordered-curved thead tr th,
.table-bordered-curved thead tr td {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
}

.table-bordered-curved thead tr th:last-child,
.table-bordered-curved thead tr td:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}

.table-bordered-curved tbody tr:first-child th,
.table-bordered-curved tbody tr:first-child td {
    border-top: 0;
}

.table-bordered-curved tbody tr td {
    border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
}

.table-bordered-curved tbody tr td:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the only solution that worked for me in Bootstrap 4. The card class only put a background behind my table.

```
<table class="table table-dark table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="rounded-top" scope="col" colspan="3">Perofrmance</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Strategy</th>
            <th scope="col">YTD</th>
            <th scope="col">Max DD</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">BTCUSD:</th>
            <td>
                <b>15</b>%
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>20</b>%
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-bottom: transparent;">
            <th scope="row" style="border-bottom-left-radius: .25rem!important;">ETHUSD:
            </th>
            <td>
                <b>12.6</b>%
            </td>
            <td style="border-bottom-right-radius: .25rem!important;">
                <b id="valueETHDD">0</b>%
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```