# Round bordered table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'd like to have an HTML table with a rounded border. I don't expect to have a round line bordering the table, but actually it's form to be rounded.

Please notice that both top row and bottom row should be rounded.

By the way, my actually table is using the "table table-bordered table-hover" css classes from bootstrap.

**This is my actual table:**

[image]

**This is what I'm trying to do:**

[image]
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: .... Use border-radius ? .... What have you tried?

Comment: See [Rounded tables in Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729638/rounded-tables-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Comment: Hi @Danko I did tried but it was not working because of the bootstrap class "table" and "table-bordered". In the end the "overflow:hidden" attribute was preventing it from working, and I'm not really sure why. But it worked anyway! Thanks to all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by adding `border-radius` to the css.

```
table {
   border-radius: 4px;
}
```

I've wrote a really quick example, so you can see output;

http://jsfiddle.net/oLrp862d/1/

---

### Edited to include code here;

```css
table {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-align: center;
    background: #c6c6c6;
}
table td {
    background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Fake Name</td>
        <td>1,337</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Fake Name</td>
        <td>1,337</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Fake Name</td>
        <td>1,337</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
table tr:first-of-type {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;}

table tr:last-of-type {
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;}
```

or put it on the table itself

```
table {
    border-radius: 5px;}
```

Comment: This is not really working. Am I missing something? I'm using all the common tags like table, thead, th, tbody, tr, td.

Comment: I'm speculating here, but it might be that you need a border in order to use border-radius, and if that's the case try adding a transparent border to your table or rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS code to round the corners:

```
.table-bordered {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Study the example below.

```css
table {
   border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid 2px red;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
  
}

tr:last-of-type td {
  border-bottom: none;
  }

tr td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
  }


td {
    text-align: center;
   border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
  border-right: solid 1px #000;
  
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>one</td>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>one</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: real solution : https://unused-css.com/blog/css-rounded-table-corners/