# borderRadius style property not rounding the edges in reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs

```
<table className="table table-striped table-bordered" style={{'borderRadius':'5px'}}>
  <tbody>
      {data}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the edges of the table to be rounded, but the above style is not working at all. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: any reason you arent just putting `style="border-radius: 5px;"`?

Comment: @DanielA.White He's probably using some templating engine

Comment: @J.Chen But there is no need to call {{}} for inline style, he is not loading it from variable

Comment: @DanielA.White, it's react js

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong, why not do it like this 
const divBorderRadius= {border-radius: '5px'} 

Then call it inside table , style={divBorderRadius},

Another thing to check if you are overriding your css in some other file. Inspect through browser

Comment: @noits, already tried that :), didnt work

Comment: Then 100% your css is being overwritten from other classes, inspect it

Comment: @noitse, ive been looking for that bug for an hour now, how could i find what exactly is overwriting it ?

Comment: It is an inline style, so only a value with `!important` can override it. Try changing the value to `5px !important` and it should definitely work. I will update my answer with that as well.

Comment: Also, this seems to be of relevance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20903465/5894241

Answer (score 8):

Based on the discussion in comments, it seems like one of the classes is overriding the inline style. The only way this could happen is if either of those classes is using `!important` to ensure that their style values take precedence over the inline values.

Keeping that in mind, I tried adding `!important` to the inline style:

```
<div className="no-borderRadiusImportant" style={{border: '1px solid black',borderRadius: '5px!important'}}>Hello, world!</div>
```

With CSS:

```
.no-borderRadiusImportant {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

It doesn't work. And based on the discussion [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1881), the issue has not been fixed yet.

So here's the solution I would suggest:

Create another class that merely adds an `!important` border radius for you. Here's how you could do it:

```
<div className="no-borderRadiusImportant border-radiusImportant">Hello, world!</div>
```

With CSS,

```
 .border-radiusImportant{
   border-radius: 5px !important;
 }
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odns10fn/1/) for various scenarios related to this.

**Original**

```
<table className="table table-striped table-bordered" style='border-radius:5px;'>
  <tbody>
      {data}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You don't need to set the border radius dynamically, if it is a constant value!

Comment: Just to be sure, have you applied `border: '1px solid black'` before applying the border-radius? Because you won't get border radius without the border (generally). Or if you have a background or box-shadow, that's okay too..

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the crucial `overflow: hidden`.

Without this crucial piece, the content overflowing from your table won't show the rounded corners.

```
<table style={{borderRadius: '5px', overflow: 'hidden'}}>
  <tbody>
      {data}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: A good solution in case there is only a background without border thickness

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

You don't need the quotes.

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html

```
<table className="table table-striped table-bordered" style={{borderRadius: '5px'}}>
  <tbody>
      {data}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use like below

```
borderBottomLeftRadius: number
borderBottomRightRadius: number
borderTopLeftRadius: number
borderTopRightRadius: number
```

Answer (score 2):

The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. 
For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'units'}} when using JSX

```
style={{borderRadius: 5 + 'px'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding another `borderCollapse: 'collapsed'` to your style object along with your `borderRadius: '5px'`.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue, if you use the Box component, you will be able to fix it. See the material ui link for more details
https://material-ui.com/pt/system/borders/

```
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
...
<Box borderRadius="50%"/>
  enter your component here
```