# How to hide first column after load for Awesome grid MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, grid, asp.net-mvc-awesome

I am using MVC Awsome grid, I want to hide first column of the grid, but struggling to do and no proper documentation for that in internet, please check below..

```
@(Html.Awe().Grid("MilkClassGrid").Load(false)
                            .CssClass("keynav")
                              .Columns(
        //new Column { Name = "Count", Width = 100, Header = "Count", ClientFormatFunc = "txtCount"},
                                  new Column { Name = "ID", Width = 100, Header = "", ClientFormatFunc = "txtslno" },
                                  new Column { Name = "MilkClasificatn", Width = 100, Header = "Classification", ClientFormatFunc = "txtClass" },
                                  new Column { Name = "MilkClassDesc", Width = 100, Header = "Description", ClientFormatFunc = "txtDesczzzz" }
        // new Column { Name = "Organic", ClientFormatFunc = "toggleButton", Width = 90}
                              )
                              .Url(@Url.Action("GetEmptyRecords"))
        //.PageSize(100)
                              .PageSize(5)
                              .Persistence(Persistence.Session)
                              .Persistence(Persistence.View) // save collapsed groups and nodes when switching between grid pages
                              .ColumnsPersistence(Persistence.Session) // save columns (width, grouping, etc..) for browser session lifetime
                              .Groupable(false)
        .Selectable(SelectionType.Single)
                              .Persistence(Persistence.View)
        //.Sortable(true)
                              .SendColumns(true)
                              .SingleColumnSort(true)
                              .Height(300)
                              .Parent("PageSize", "PageSize")
                              .Parent("MilkType", "search")
                              )
```

**Edited**

function txtslno(model, name) {

```
    var as = arryLen.length;
    as = parseInt(as) + parseInt(counta);
    var val = model[name];
    if (!val) val = "";
    if (as <= counta) {
        counta++;
        var html = "<input type='text' class='count11' disabled='disabled'  name='" + name + "' id='GetList_" + counta + "_slno'  value='" + escapeChars(val) + "'/>";

        return html;
    } else {
        return "<input type='text' class='count11' disabled='disabled'  name='" + name + "' id='GetList_" + as + "_slno1'  value='" + escapeChars(val) + "'/>";
    }
}
```

I have tried by calling a javascript function in Load function, but didn't getting, please help me anyone. Thank you

Comment: If you want to hide first column, then why to bind it in first place?

Comment: I want value of first column and pass as parameter, but by default it should not be visible to user, just like hidden field

Comment: Show us your `txtslno` function? It should work if you write your custom CSS there.

Comment: Also you have one more - `ClientFormat` have your tried that? Example here - http://demo.aspnetawesome.com/GridDemo/CustomFormat

Comment: But I want to call javascript or hide after grid loaded..

Comment: I dont see any where in your JQuery function, that you are trying to hide the control. So please correct it and add style - display:none.

Answer (score 0):

Just inspect the page with chrome dev tools and hide the first row of the grid using css.

Similar to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30681422/769871

How to select first row of something with pure css:

[Select only the first row in a table with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525503/select-only-the-first-row-in-a-table-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the value that the first Column is showing there's no need to declare the column at all. The row model and what you are rendering in the grid row are separate things.

There's a demo for hiding columns here: https://demo.aspnetawesome.com/GridShowHideColumnsApiDemo

Basically it would be something like this:

```
var g = $('#Grid1');
g.data('o').columns[0].Hid = 1;
g.data('api').render() // or .load()
```