# Regular Expression with global flag is not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string

```
$$_### ABC ###_$$ $$_### PQR ###_$$ $$_### XYZ ###_$$
```

I wanted to replace `$$_###` with and `li` tag and `###_$$` with a closing `li` tag.

So the final output should be `<li>ABC</li><li>PQR</li><li>XYZ</li>`

What I have used is this

```
str = $$_### ABC ###_$$ $$_### PQR ###_$$ $$_### XYZ ###_$$;

new_str = (str.replace(/$$_###/g,'<li>')).replace(/###_$$/g,'</li>');
```

It doesn't seem to be working.

`new_str = (str.replace('$$_###','<li>').replace('###_$$','</li>');` worked fine, but of course i want a global replacement.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$` is a special character in regex which asserts that we are at the end of a line. So you need to escape the dollar symbol in-order to match a literal `$` symbol.

```
new_str = str.replace(/\$\$_###/g,'<li>').replace(/###_\$\$/g,'</li>');
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, Avinash. I was breaking my head on this for a couple of hours. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hereafter you don't need hours to solve a problem since you find our StackOverflow site :-)..

Answer (score 0):

$ is a special character in regex meaning end of line. You need to escape each one with a '\' in your regex literal per [regular_expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

The replace is just doing a literal replace of text so it requires no escaping.

Here is a link where you can see it working and test it - [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uY1rY1/2)

Comment: Thanks Cole. Was greatly helpful.